# c# how to fix foreach , when i try to console.write elements in my list<string>

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I am learning c# and i have some problem with my code. I have no idea why i cant use foreach in my example . What can i do to fix this problem? Any suggestions?

```
  public class Company
  {
    List<string> workers;
    public Company()
    {
        workers= new List<string>();
    }
    public void AddWorker(string x)
    {
        workers.Add(x);
    }
  }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Company c1= new Company();
        c1.AddWorker("Adam Snow");
        c1.AddWorker("John Big");
        c1.AddWorker("Chris Zen");

        foreach (var x in c1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
     }
```

Comment: probably because you can´t iterate a `Company`? I suppose you want to iterate the `Workers` in that company.

Comment: `foreach (var x in c1.workers)` but you have to make `workers` public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do workers list public and loop in c1.workers then it's ok.

```
public List<string> workers;
```

then

```
foreach (var x in c1.workers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer adding a new property `public IEnumerable<string> Workers => workers;` rather than exposing a list that other code could then modify.

Comment: Yes, defining property looks better solution.

Comment: Thanks , its very simple answer .

Comment: @ShadeToD Do be aware that if you make it public, other code can do nasty stuff like `c1.workers = null` or `c1.workers.Clear()`

Answer (score 5):

In the line

```
foreach (var x in c1)
```

you try to iterate over your instance of `Company` which is not enumerable. You want to iterate over the `workers` list of that instance.

One solution is to make `workers` a public property:

```
public class Company
{
    List<string> workers;
    public IEnumerable<string> Workers { get { return workers; } }

    // shortened for brevity
}
```

and then you can use `foreach` like that:

```
foreach (var x in c1.Workers) // <- access the Workers property here
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

---

As Dmitry suggested, you may want to expose the workers list only as readonly, so that users of that class cannot change the list's content from outside:

```
public class Company
{
    List<string> workers;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Workers
    { 
        get { return workers.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    // shortened for brevity
}
```

Comment: since backing field `workers` is of `List<string>` type I suggest returning at least `IReadOnlyList<String>` instead of `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 3):

If you want iterate over `Company` class instance, `Company` has to implement `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
public class Company : IEnumerable<string>{
  ...
  public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() {
    return workers.GetEnumerator();
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return workers.GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

having done this you can put

```
Company c1 = new Company();

foreach (var x in c1) {
  Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but maybe a little too advanced for someone asking this kind of question.

Comment: I don't think when you add a worker to company you should iterate over company.

Comment: @ShadeToD it works for this special case, but it's a design problem. It doesn't help you if in your next step you add departments, offices or any other properties of a company that you might want to iterate, too.

Comment: i get an 2 errors when i try do this .1st error 'Company' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'Company.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerator'. 2nd Using the generic type IEnumerator<T> requires 1 type arguments.

Comment: @ShadeToD: the implmentation depends on what you import with `using`, C# version etc. `System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
      return this.GetEnumerator();
    }` instead of `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` in the answer